# Syntax coloring with Vim and Fish-Shell

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, fish, vim-syntax-highlighting

What is the best editor for fish scripts? I mean an editor which can properly highlight, indent and syntax check.

I found [the vim-fish project](https://github.com/dag/vim-fish), but I am still scratching my head as to how to install it locally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just copy all those files and directories inside the repository into `~/.vim`. However, the recommended way is to use something like [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) or [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)

For vundle:

Run these commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle
touch ~/.vimrc
```

Then add this to your `~/.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'dag/vim-fish'

filetype plugin indent on
```

Next time you launch vim you can run the command `:BundleInstall` to get `vim-fish` installed.

If you want this to work with `funced` and other potential scripts that should use the fish-syntax you can add something like this to `~/.vim/ftdetect/fish.vim`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead fish_funced set ft=fish
```

Comment: In addition, if you have Pathogen installed just clone it to the ~/.vim/bundle folder so you have ~/.vim/bundle/vim-fish/. Works if you open a .fish file with Vim but doesn't work with `funced`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively I would advice you to install it via [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) which is quite minimalist:

```
curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

Add the following code to your `.vimrc` file:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Make sure you use single quotes for comment

Plug 'dag/vim-fish'

" Add plugins to &runtimepath
call plug#end()
```

Reload `.vimrc` and `:PlugInstall` to install plugins.